# Update all records in database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this:

```
$keys = Keys_Info::all();

foreach ($keys as $key)
{
          $rank = 1; //Example.. In real it's variable..
          DB::table('keys_info')
                      ->where('id', $key->id)
                      ->update(['rank' => $rank]);
}
```

This only updates first row, not all. How get this to update all rows?

**EDIT**

```
foreach($keys as $key)
{
   print $key->id; //Example printing all keys
   foreach($results as $results)
   {
            print $key->id; //Example printing all keys

            if (in_array($key->example, $array))
            {
               print $key->id; //Example printing first row key!
               $rank = 1; //Example
               DB::table('keywords_info')
                           ->where('id', $key->id)
                           ->update(['url_rank' => $rank]);
            }
   }
}
```

I didn't explain well at first, this is whole code I use. I figured out that it does not work in IF statement

Comment: can you share the data structure of $keys

Comment: that's because where evaluates  to false

Comment: Please see edited question

Answer (score 1):

As you are updating all rows you can simply do like below

```
 DB::table('keys_info')->update(['rank' => $rank]);
```

If you still want to pass the id you can do like below

```
//Fetch all ids in array
$keys=Keys_Info::pluck('id')  OR Keys_Info::value('id')
//apply in query
DB::table('keys_info')->whereIn('id', $keys)->update(['rank' => $rank]);
```